# Datomic: Can't evaluate d/transaction from REPL

Tags: clojure, datomic

I am new to Datomic on-prem. But I'm not able to call a d/transact from my editor.

I started my peer server and my transactor.

```
bin/run -m datomic.peer-server -h localhost -p 8998 -a myaccesskey,mysecret -d pensine,datomic:dev://localhost:4334/pensine
```

```
bin/transactor config/samples/dev-transactor-template.properties
```

I have wrote this in my buffer

```
(def cfg {:server-type :peer-server
          :access-key "myaccesskey"
          :secret "mysecret"
          :endpoint "localhost:8998"})

(def client (d/client cfg))


(def conn (d/connect client {:db-name "datomic:dev://localhost:4334/pensine"}))

// Loaded everything above in the REPL then tried to evaluate the expression below.

(d/transact conn {:tx-data [{:db/ident :red}]}) // this throw the error below
@(d/transact conn {:tx-data [{:db/ident :red}]}) // this throw the error below
```

REPL ouput:

```
Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at datomic.client.api.protocols/fn$G (protocols.clj:72).
No implementation of method: :transact of protocol: #'datomic.client.api.protocols/Connection found for class: clojure.lang.Var$Unbound
```

Answer (score 0):

In my dev in-memory setup I'm starting the peer server with argument

```
-d pensine,datomic:mem://pensine
```

and connect using

```
(def conn (d/connect client {:db-name "pensine"}))
```

In this setup you don't need a transactor.

Hope it helps, I haven't done a more comprehensive setup yet.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify Erik's answer slightly, the `-d` argument given when starting the peer-server, consists of two parts:

```
-d <<dbname>>,<<storage-uri>>
```

and it's the former `dbname` that should be passed to the `connect` function in the argument map.

From the [Datomic Peer Server documentation](https://docs.datomic.com/pro/client/peer-server.html):

> A dbname can consist of alphanumeric characters plus the hyphen '-'.
>
> The storage-uri is described in the documentation for connect, e.g.
>
> datomic:ddb://us-east-1/my-datomic-table/my-db
>
> The -d option may be passed multiple times to serve multiple databases
> from a single peer server. As a development convenience, a Peer Server
> can also serve transient, memory-only databases by passing a mem URI
> to the Peer Server command.